# Can I initialize a global variable by another global variable in JAVA?

Tags: java, global-variables

```
static class Variable{
        public static File myfile;
        public static String path = "E:\\java_file\\AccountData.txt";
        Variable.myfile = new File(Variable.path);
}
```

when I trying to create a file like:

```
protected static void FileCreate(){
    try { 
        if (Variable.myfile.createNewFile())
            System.out.println("File created"); 
        else
            System.out.println("File already exists");
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.err.println(e); 
    }
}
```

and it's appear an error:

> Syntax error on token "myfile", VariableDeclaratorId expected after
>   this token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
public static String path = "E:\\java_file\\AccountData.txt";
public static File myfile = new File(path);
```